# Disabled Automatic date value changes during Next/Previous actions in jQuery DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm working with Trent Richardson's great Datetimepicker plugin for jQuery UI's datepicker.

One issue however that I wish to resolve is the fact that when you select a field, and then navigate through it, the date value changes in the input field. So, if you selected a date, and then decided to navigate to view other options, it changes the date during the process.

For an example, you can look at the examples page right [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#slider_examples) (using dropdowns instead of sliders ).

Here is my initialization code:

```
$('input[name=valueTextField]').addClass('datepicker');

                $( ".datepicker" ).datetimepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy ',
                        timeText: 'Test',
                        controlType: 'select',
                        timeFormat: "h:mm TT",
                        ampm: true,
                        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, dpInst, tpInst) {
                            alert(dpInst);
                            alert(dpInst.dateDefined);
                            if(!tpInst.timeDefined && !dpInst.dateDefined) {
                                this.value = '';
                                dpInst.dateDefined = null;
                            }
                            if (dpInst.dateDefined) {

                            }
                        },
                        onSelect: function(date, dpInst) {
                            dpInst.dateDefined = true;
                        }

                });
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("meta_datepicker");
                $('input[name=valueTextField]').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

You can see a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3DzTu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the previous value after each `keyup` and `select`, and restore it during a `changeMonthYear` or `close`:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datetimepicker({
    ...
    onSelect: function() {
        $(this).data("oldValue",this.value);
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, dpInst, tpInst) {
        this.value = $(this).data("oldValue");
    },
    onClose: function() {
        this.value = $(this).data("oldValue");
    }
}).keyup(function() {
    $(this).data("oldValue",this.value);
});
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3DzTu/4/). Not pretty, but gets the job done... Some edge cases:

- While you're navigating the pop-up, everything works fine, but if you try to edit the text field it goes back to the current month (not really a problem though).
- If you paste some date into the text field **using your mouse** and then immediatly click "next" or "previous", it won't keep the correct value (don't know an easy cross-browsers solution for that though).
- If you change months and then select a time, the date will also change to the current month, as pointed out by @streetlight. To prevent that, a custom `controlType` might be used, but a full implementation is beyond the scope of this answer.

**Update:** as @streetlight pointed out yet *another* problem - after using the "Now" button everything seems to become "glitchy" (sometimes it uses the old value, sometimes the new) - I'm reaching the conclusion this is too much work to do in user code. Assuming that in fact it's better for usability not to automatically change the value while navigating the calendar, I'd suggest a RFE be opened with the jQuery team to propose this option.

Comment: This is great! However, if you navigate through and press 'done', it saves the altered date instead of the original one. In addition,  in the example if it starts blank you cannot select a date, and if you navigate from a blank value it inserts 'undefined' when merged with my former code. Do you know any way around these? I wish there was an easy way to alter the API if necessary!

Comment: For the first problem, I don't know a solution yet (but will keep looking). For the second, that's really weird - if `oldValue` is undefined it shouldn't affect the value... I'd suggest trying to check it using `if ( $(this).data("oldValue") )` before setting, see if that solves your problem. (*Edit:* got it - see the update)

Comment: That's great! For some reason the first problem is solved on my computer, but it is not working when I replicate it on the JSFiddle. One last thing I noticed, which may be a stretch -- if you change the time but not the date, it changes both to the 'datetimepicker' time instead of the original time with the new date. Is it in the same ballpark to separate these so a user could change the time on the original date without reseting the entire date? Or maybe just apply the same principle to the time fields as well? Thank you for all of your help so far too!

Comment: I don't see in the API any way to differentiate between a date `onSelect` and a time `onSelect`, so it will require some effort on your part (whether it pays up or not is up to you). My suggestions to get started are: 1) create a custom `controlType` for that; or: b) if you don't mind modifying the sources, look at `_onTimeChange` and change what's needed (warn: this method is called on several other events, like when the popup is open and when the month is changed).

Comment: One last issue that I spotted! If you select the 'now' option, then navigate no 'oldValue' is saved. Is there anyway to set the 'oldValue' to that if someone posts for New? (I seriously can't thank you enough for your help! Sorry I keep pushing the scope of this issue; just thought it would be better to include it all here then spread it across other posts. You're great!)

Comment: You're right, and IMHO this is getting too complicated... I agree with you that usability-wise automatically changing dates is not good, but unfortunatly the date(time)picker APIs are very poor in this regard. One last thought: **after** the date(time)picker is created, it's possible to select individual elements (such as the "Now" button, the selects, etc) and to try to customize their behavior (by binding different event handlers to them). Tricky, but might work...